# Load the listview item 10 by 10 when scrolling

Tags: xamarin.forms.listview

I am using xamarin.forms.

I have listview with 100 items. I want to show only 10 items initially when loading. When scrolling upto 10 item, then next 10 item should be loaded with activityindicator. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ListView.ItemAppearing, for example:

```
var listView = new ListView { ... };

listView.ItemAppearing += async (sender, e) =>
{
    var items = listView.ItemsSource as IList;

    if (items == null
        || items.Count == 0)
        return;

    if (e.Item != items[items.Count - 1])
        return;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The end of the list, load more!");
};
```